# Python program for the Longest Substring Without Repeating Characters

Tags: python, programming-challenge

I write my Python program below for [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/) Leetcode problem:

> Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
>
> Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "abcabcbb"
> Output: 3
> Explanation: The answer is "abc", with the length of 3.
> ```
>
> Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "bbbbb"
> Output: 1
> Explanation: The answer is "b", with the length of 1.
> ```
>
> Example 3:
>
> ```
> Input: s = "pwwkew"
> Output: 3
> Explanation: The answer is "wke", with the length of 3.
> Notice that the answer must be a substring, "pwke" is a subsequence and not a substring.
> ```

```
class Solution(object):
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        if s == "":
            return 0
        L = 1
        tmp0 = [(i,i+1) for i in range(len(s)-1)]
        # print(tmp0)
        # print(10*'-.')
        while L<=len(set(s)):
            tmp = []
            for x in tmp0:
                i, j = x
                if j < len(s) and s[j] not in s[i:j]:
                    tmp.append((i,j+1))
                    # print(tmp)
                    # print(s[i:j+1])
            if not tmp:
                break
            else:
                tmp0 = tmp
                L += 1
        return L
```

It passes all the tests but it runs slow. I am aware there are other faster solutions. But I would appreciate a code review for the one above. I would like to know if my idea is intrinsically slow or if it is still possible to make the code faster using the same idea. I am guessing `s[j] not in s[i:j]` is an expensive piece in the code.

Answer (score 1):

#### Performance

> I am guessing `s[j] not in s[i:j]` is an expensive piece in the code.

You guess correctly. This is expensive, because to check if a character exists in the range `s[i:j]`, the values in the range are compared to the target one by one. This is a \$O(n)\$ (linear) operation, where `n` is the length of the range. It would be better to use a `set` data structure, which would make it an \$O(1)\$ (constant) time operation to check if a value exists or not.

Another part of the slowness is the algorithm. It checks all possible ranges of length 1, 2, 3, ... until finding a range that contains duplicates, or the length of the input is reached.
If I'm not mistaken the time complexity of this is \$O(n^3)\$, where `n` is the length of the input.
Because there are about `\$n^2\$` possible sub-ranges, and for each range there is a linear lookup.

The optimal solution uses a sliding window which shrinks and grows:

- Setup some variables to use to track state, as we process the characters in the input

  - Track the unique characters in the current range in `seen`
  - Track the beginning of the range in `left`
  - Track the longest range of unique characters we've seen in `longest`
  - Track the length of the current range in `length`
- For each character `c` in the input at `index`:

  - if `c` is not in `seen`, we have a new unique character

    - add it to `seen`
    - increment `length`
    - update `longest` if `length > longest`
  - since `c` is a duplicate, shrink the range from the left, until the previous `c`

    - while `s[left]` is not `c`:

      - remove `s[left]` from `seen`
      - increment `left`
      - decrement `length`
    - since at this point `left` points to the position of the previous `c`, increment it one more time

This algorithm runs in \$O(n)\$, which is significantly faster, and it finds the correct solution in a single pass over the input string.
It's worth noting that it uses additional storage for `seen`,
but the size of that is the size of the alphabet,
which is constant, therefore the space complexity is \$O(1)\$.

---

Another, smaller performance issue is the unnecessary `set` creation in this loop condition:

> ```
> while L<=len(set(s)):
> ```

Every time this loop condition is evaluated,
a `set` is created from the input and then thrown away.
This is an expensive operation,
and since the result of this evaluation is always the same,
it's better to executed it once before the loop and store it in a variable.

On closer look, the condition is always `True`,
because `L` can never be higher than the number of unique characters in the input.
So you could as well replace the condition with `True`.

#### Handling corner cases and other special conditions

I always look with suspicion at conditions targeting special cases,
in the posted code these:

> ```
> if s == "":
>     return 0
>
> if not tmp:
>     break
> ```

Is it possible to reorganize the code to get these special cases handled with the normal flow?

```
L = 0
tmp0 = [(i, i + 1) for i in range(len(s))]
while tmp0:
    tmp = []
    for i, j in tmp0:
        if j < len(s) and s[j] not in s[i:j]:
            tmp.append((i, j + 1))
    tmp0 = tmp
    L += 1

return L
```

With fewer conditions, the code is shorter.
Less to read, less to understand, less mental burden.

#### Iterating over a list of tuples

Instead of:

> ```
> for x in tmp0:
>     i, j = x
> ```

You can let Python expand the tuples to a pair of variables in the loop statement directly:

```
for i, j in tmp0:
```

#### Follow the Python style guide

[PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) is the official style guide for Python,
it's good to follow it. I will highlight here just a few examples.

---

An empty string is treated as `false` in a boolean context. So instead of:

> ```
> if s == "":
>     return 0
> ```

The recommended writing style is:

```
if not s:
    return 0
```

---

It's recommended to add spaces around operators, for example instead of:

> ```
> tmp0 = [(i,i+1) for i in range(len(s)-1)]
> while L<=len(set(s)):
> ```

The preferred writing style:

```
tmp0 = [(i, i + 1) for i in range(len(s) - 1)]
while L <= len(set(s)):
```

---

The naming recommendation for local variables is `snake_case`,
so `L` should be renamed.
`length` or `longest` would be good self-explanatory names here.

I would rename most of the variables to be more descriptive:

```
longest = 0
left_right_pairs = [(i, i + 1) for i in range(len(s))]

while left_right_pairs:
    next_left_right_pairs = []
    for left, right in left_right_pairs:
        if right < len(s) and s[right] not in s[left:right]:
            next_left_right_pairs.append((left, right + 1))

    left_right_pairs = next_left_right_pairs
    longest += 1

return longest
```